# Fade in UITableViewCell row by row in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I am new to swift, I am trying to have a UITableView and the cells will be animated to appear one by one. How can I do that? Also, if the newly appeared row of cell not on the screen (hiding below the table). How can I move the table up when each cell appear?

```
    var tableData1: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]

     override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
           tableView.scrollEnabled=false
    tableView.alpha=0.0
            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(3), target: self, selector: "animateTable", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tableData1.count
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

        let cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TblCell
        cell.lblCarName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified;
return cell
}

func animateTable() {

//what should be the code?//
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the UITableView, the rows are prepared automatically for you when they get to be in your "range vision". I'm assuming you are, at least not initially, being able to scroll the tableView, so we would scroll it programmatically making the rows appear as it goes. How are we doing that? Actually UITableView has a method that let us scroll it to a specific row:

```
scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath : NSIndexPath, atScrollPosition : UITableViewScrollPosition, animated : Bool);
```

I'm too tired to write the code, so I'm going to try to explain. First, for every cell you set alpha to 0, as soon as they get loaded (cellForRowAtIndexPath).
Then let's suppose our screen fits the 5 first rows. You are going to animate their alphas sequentially (using UIView.animateWithDuration ) until the fifth one (index 4), then you are going to scrollToRowAtIndexPath passing NSIndexPath using 5, then 6,... until the rest of them (using scrollPosition = .Bottom). And for each of them, you would animate as soon as they get loaded. Just remember to put some time between this interactions. (animate first, run NSTimer to the second, and it goes on). And the boolean animated should be true of course.

Comment: Thanks! I set the alpha to 0 already. The thing I am not sure is how to make the cell appear one by one? They appear at the same time? How can I control or assign each cell?

Comment: The method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" that you implemented can be called to get the cell of a specificRow. To make them appear one by one you call them using that NSTime.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval. Passing for example 1 for the first row, 2 for the second, 3 for the third.

Answer (score 12):

### Step-1

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method where initialize your cell, hide it like that;

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {
    let cell: TblCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TblCell
    cell.continueLabel.textAlignment = .justified
    cell.contentView.alpha = 0
    return cell
}
```

### Step-2

Let's make fade animation. `UITableViewDelegate` has `willDisplayCell` method which is able to detect that when you scroll to top or bottom, first cell will display on the window.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, animations: {
        cell.contentView.alpha = 1
    })   
}
```

Your fade animation is on the progress. The most important thing is that you can not setup your cell's alpha directly in runtime because iOS is doing some special internal handling with the cell as part of your `UITableView` and ignores your setup. So if you setup your cell's `contentView`, everything's gonna be fine.

Comment: I tried this and the code works but I would like a slightly different behaviour. Your code fades all of the rows at the same time. I want only every new row of the tableView (bottom row) to fade. How could I re-use your code to accomplish that? Also as an alternative could I somehow delete the bottom row after 2 seconds or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To appear each visible cell one by one, you can do it by playing with alpha and duration value.

```
extension UITableView {

    func fadeVisibleCells() {

        var delayDuration: TimeInterval = 0.0

        for cell in visibleCells {

            cell.alpha = 0.0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: delayDuration) {
                cell.alpha = 1.0
            }

            delayCounter += 0.30
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code which can get you started. In my [COBezierTableView](https://github.com/knutigro/COBezierTableView)
 I subclassed `UITableView` and override the `layoutSubviews`method. In there you can manipulate the cells according to their relative position in the view. In this example I fade them out in the bottom.

```
import UIKit

public class MyCustomTableView: UITableView {

    // MARK: - Layout

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let indexpaths = indexPathsForVisibleRows!
        let totalVisibleCells = indexpaths.count - 1
        if totalVisibleCells <= 0 { return }

        for index in 0...totalVisibleCells {
            let indexPath = indexpaths[index] 
            if let cell = cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                if let superView = superview {
                    let point = convertPoint(cell.frame.origin, toView:superView)
                    let pointScale = point.y / CGFloat(superView.bounds.size.height)
                    cell.contentView.alpha = 1 - pointScale
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell .alpha = 1.0
         let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 3000, 1200)
       //let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 250, 0, 1250)
     //let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 250, 1250, 0)
      // let transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -250, 300, 120)


   cell.layer.transform = transform




    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        cell.alpha = 1.0
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
    }
}
```

Comment: please add some statement about your logic explaining your code ! it will be great!

Answer (score 0):

I think this method will be a great solution.

> - Set all cell alpha to 0
> - animate them in tableView(_:,willDisplay:,forRowAt:)
> - set a delay for every `indexPath.row`

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.05 * Double(indexPath.row), animations: {
        cell.alpha = 1
    })
}
```